# PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider UsernameNotFound exception returns 401 instead of denied page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I use spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and spring-security 4.0.1.RELEASE.

There is RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter and PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider. I want my application to show 'denied' page, if user service throws UsernameNotFoundException.
Actually, application shows basic HTTP authorization form (simple browser popup for credentials) and provides 401 response if it cancelled.

Here is my configuration:

```
<s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/report/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <s:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <s:custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <s:form-login
            authentication-failure-url="/denied.jsp"/>
</s:http>

<b:bean id="preAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
    <b:property name="principalRequestHeader" value="REMOTE_USER"/>
    <b:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authManager"/>
</b:bean>

<s:authentication-manager id="authManager">
    <s:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
</s:authentication-manager>

<b:bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.db.dump.tool.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
```

Class UserDetailsServiceImpl just checks user with DB and throws UsernameNotFoundException if user is not found. Maybe here is a problem?
Please, advise.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is due to the ExceptionTranslationFilter translating the final exception as:

> Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

User is anonymous because your UserDetailsService threw exception. You are getting 401 response because it has been implemented that way in the [BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.html) which acts as authentication entry point in case of a non XMLHttpRequest (your case) with anonymous user principal.

In case you wish to show an access denied page instead (not giving an anonymous user chance to authenticate), you need to plug in your own [AuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html) using the entry-point-ref attribute on the http element (and then may be also let the AccessDeniedHandler come into picture). The resulting implmentation would look something like this:

```
import static javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;

public class CustomAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setStatus(SC_FORBIDDEN); /* You can also call an access denied handler here and let it handle some meaningful exception that you pass into the handle method. */
    }
}
```

PS: Of course you'll need to configure your new authentication entry point as a spring bean before it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which I found is to set no authorities for user and do not throw any exceptions. We have 403 error page in this case, which could be customized by access-denied-handler.